# Start an Android App when an "unknown tag type" is scanned

Tags: android, embedded, nfc, spi

I am working on an Android NFC reader project in which I use the AS3953 NFC chip. according to the [datasheet](http://ams.com/eng/Products/NFC-HF-RFID/NFC-HF-Interface-and-Sensor-Tags/AS3953): This NFC chip could be used

> Where log data is stored periodically by the microcontroller and can
>   then be read by the PCD even when the microcontroller is not powered.

And this is exactly what I am trying to do, read passively the NFC tag. The problem is that my Android phone doesn't recognise the tag when it's not connected to the microcontroller. I have just a noise when I scan the tag and no information appear. I tried with another smartphone and I had the same behaviour with a small message: "unknown tag type".

My question is:
How can I start an Android App when an "unknown tag type" is detected. I tried the three Android intent handlers: TAG_DISCOVERED, TECH_DISCOVERED and NDEF_DSICOVERED, but none of these solutions has worked.

N.B: according to the [datasheet](http://ams.com/eng/Products/NFC-HF-RFID/NFC-HF-Interface-and-Sensor-Tags/AS3953), The AS3953A supports ISO 14443A up to Level-4

N.B2: when I use the constructor demokit I can read the EEPROM values when the NFC is supplied via the SPI interface.

[image: The AS3953 chip connected the Demoboard microcontroller]

[image: The stand-alone tag that I want to read]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the manufacturer "ams". They said that this tag (AS3953 HW) is not NFC Forum standards compliant (contrary to what is mentioned in the datasheet). So to read passively the tag I have to code their **proprietary commands** (a list is provided in the datasheet) into my app.